# String Parsing in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to parse a string something like this:

Input "20:00" - output would be "20"
Input "02:30" - output would be "2"
Input "00:30" - output would be "".

This is how I have written, I don't like the way I am doing it, looking for more efficient way to do this may be in a single scan. Any ideas?

```
private String getString(final String inputString)
{
    String inputString = "20:00"; // This is just for example       
    final String[] splittedString = inputString.split(":");
    final String firstString = splittedString[0];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < firstString.length(); i++)
    {
        if (firstString.charAt(i) != '0')
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    String outputString = "";
    if (i != firstString.length())
    {
        outputString = firstString.substring(i, firstString.length());
    }

    return outputString;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final String firstString = splittedString[0];
int value = Integer.parseInt(firstString);
return value == 0 ? "" : Integer.toString(value);
```

Comment: `String  v = Integer.toString( Integer.parseInt( input.split(":")[0] ) ); return v.equals("0") ? "" : v;`

Comment: what is I also want to allow " 2:30" spaces in input. In such scenario, i belive Interger.parseInt will blow up.

Comment: @Rishi try passing firstString.trim() to parseInt()

Answer (score 1):

You could use `java.util.Scanner`.
Assuming your data is always formatted `\d\d:\d\d`, you could do something like this.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter(":");
int n = s.nextInt();
if (n == 0 ) {
  return "";
} else {
  return Integer.toString(n)
}
```

That way you don't have to scan the string twice--once for the split and once for checking the first split. And, if your data is more complex, you can make your scanner more sophisticated using regexps or something.